# Bug in C++ thread class that causes it to consume 100% CPU on exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following C++ thread class, and all new thread instances are implemented as objects of classes inheriting form `Thread`. To start a thread an object is created and then `run()` is called on the object.
The problem I am facing is that the CPU usage of a thread is rising to 100% after the `thread_main` function exits. So for instance if an object were to extend this class, and its thread_main were to just be a `printf ( "%s", "Hello World" ); return ;`, then starting a thread would cause the CPU usage to jump 100% on a multicore processor.
What am I dong wrong ?

```
  class Thread {
  public:
    Thread ( ) 
    {
    }

    virtual ~Thread ( ) {}

    /// function to be called after construction to start thread
    void run ( )
    {
      pthread_create ( &pthread_obj_, NULL, &(static_start_routine), this );
    }

    /// called by the thread that has created this thread when it has nothing to do
    /// apart from waiting for this thread to exit
    void stop ( )
    {
      pthread_join ( pthread_obj_, NULL );
    }

  protected:
    /// implement this function in child class. This is sort of the main 
    /// point of control for Thread class and derived classes. 
    /// Exiting this function means the thread is closed
    virtual void thread_main ( ) = 0; 

  private:
    pthread_t pthread_obj_;

    /// The function supplied as argument to pthread_create must be a static function 
    /// and hence the real start of the thread is Thread::thread_main 
    static void * static_start_routine ( void * p_thread_subclass_object_ )
    {
      reinterpret_cast < Thread * >(p_thread_subclass_object_)->thread_main ( );
      return NULL;
    }

  };

class ClientThread : public Thread
{
public:
  ClientThread ( DebugLogger & r_dbglogger_, const int r_client_id_, const int r_fd_ ) 
   : ( dbglogger_ ( r_dbglogger_ ), client_id_ ( r_client_id_ ), fd_ ( r_fd_ )
  {}

  virtual ~ClientThread ( ) {}

  void thread_main ( ) 
  {
     GenericORSRequestStruct t_client_request_; 
     int retval = read ( fd_, & t_client_request_, sizeof ( GenericORSRequestStruct ) ) ;
     // processing code
  }
private:
  DebugLogger & dbglogger_; 
  const int client_id_; 
  const int fd_;
};

// relevant part from "accept" thread
void ClientReceiver::thread_main ( )
{
  while ( int fd_ = tcp_server_socket_.Accept ( ) )
    {
        client_id_ ++;
        ClientThread * t_client_thread_ = new CleintThread ( dbglogger_, client_id_, fd_ ) ;
        t_client_thread_->run ( ); // starts the thread
    }
}
// so Thread::stop() is not being called anywhere.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling `run()` multiple times on the same object?

Comment: Why are you making your own thread class instead of using [one that's already been documented, tested, and used by at least tens of thousands of people](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/thread/)?

Comment: First of all [Not the actual problem though ] no need to use reinterpret_cast , you should be using static_cast.But you have to post the code where you are actually running the thread.The one you have posted is incomplete. We need to know how you are actually using the class to run the thread.

Comment: @ildjarn: I agree Boost threads are lot easier to work with compared to pthreads.But OP seems to be in a process to learn making his own thread classes and it is the perfectly right way to begin with.

Comment: @ildjarn: I am unfamiliar with boost::threads, but will read up. Are there any latency concerns one might have in using boost::thread ? We are building an application that is super latency sensitive and I wanted to make sure that operations such as thread context switching aren't slowed down in any way. Is boost::thread still the one you'd recommend ?

Comment: @Humble Debugger: boost::thread does not incur additional running overhead versus ordinary threads; it uses regular OS threads under the hood, and just provides you a cross-platform interface.

Comment: @Andres Jaan Tack Thanks. Will look into it. Given the above code is there in a ton of code, would appreciate some color on this.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions...

- Make sure you are linking to a thread-safe version of C/C++ run-time library (visa-vi printf).
- Also make sure you wait on the new thread and not let main() return until the thread has actually finished executing. Calling printf() after main() might be problematic.
- Make sure the Thread object is actually alive until `stop()` (e.g. not deleted by the parent thread).

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, here, with "calling printf() after main() might be problematic."